# Install phpredis for PHP 5.6 on OSX does not work

Tags: php, macos, redis, php-5.6, phpredis

I'm trying to install phpredis on mac using php 5.6.
I run the following commands:

```
1. git clone https://www.github.com/phpredis/phpredis.git
2. cd phpredis
3. phpize && ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

But when I run the command 3 I get the following error:

```
In file included from /Users/user1/phpredis/redis.c:25:
In file included from ./php_redis.h:20:
./common.h:12:10: fatal error: 'zend_smart_str.h' file not found
#include <zend_smart_str.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [redis.lo] Error 1
```

There's another way to install it?

Answer (score 0):

from [github](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/blob/develop/INSTALL.markdown#installation-from-pecl) you can use ``pecl as another way to install it.

But it also define some command you could run if there is error when install [link](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/blob/develop/INSTALL.markdown#installation-on-osx)

Comment: thanks for answer! But I'm using mac majore, does it works the same?

Comment: For `pecl` yes. For the other I think